# Getting email address from text box and send it

Tags: c#

```
if (txtEmail.Text != null)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("localhost", 587);
        sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyEmail@gmail.com", 
                                               "MyPassword");
        sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("MyEmail@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "Sending Test";
        mailMessage.Body = "this is a test message your UserName is"
                            + txtUserName.Text;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string mailBox = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
        mailMessage.To.Add(mailBox);
        sc.Send(mailMessage);
        lblMessage.Text = "Mail send...";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "you should enter your email address";
}
```

Alright first of all sorry about my weak English language, however i read lots of articles about how to send an E-mail with C# and i know how to do it...

But my problem is when I want to send E-mail that entered to a text box and I put for example

> (E-mailAddress.text) into a MailAddress or MailMessage.Add,

it threw me an exception that says

> (The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: addresses)

and shows me the MailAdress or MailMessage object that filled with E-mailAddress.text instead with a string like "abc@yahoo.com" and even in further i'm not capable to send the E-mail  ... if there is any help i'd be so glad

Comment: Can you please add your code here? That would show us where you are going wrong.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code and HTML that you have developed so far?

Comment: Please post your code where you are adding the email address to your email object,

Comment: EDit your question and add the code used to fill your MailAddress and send the message.

Comment: So has the user entered something at all? I think that field is mandatory so you shoud check first if something was entered.

Comment: -1, Question is not clear and is confusing. Not clear what is expected ..

Comment: -1. Your Problem is not your english, your Problem is that you lack even the smallest attempt to make your Point clear with examples. Noone will be able to help you as noone can understand where your Problem is. Logic, not langauge, is the Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would change

```
txtEmail.Text != null
```

to

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text)
```

Then i would try to do it this way:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text.Trim()));
```

instead of

```
string mailBox = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
mailMessage.To.Add(mailBox);
```

Also i would implement a method to validated the entered email address to avoid invalid addresses :)

Comment: tanx Daniel that was so helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check for:

```
if (txtEmail.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
```

instead of

```
if (txtEmail.Text != null)
```